# Pass data between pages ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net, forms, html

I have two ASP.NET pages.

One of them have a table with some data that came from javascript, each row has a button-link that opens pop-up page. I need to pass the data contained in the selected row to the single row table in pop-up,

what a better way to do that?

Comment: Can you post some code so we can see what you've tried.

Comment: You probably don't really want to use a pop-up window like this  (you'll have problems with pop-up blockers etc when your code goes to production): consider using a dynamic div on the same page.

Answer (score 1):

If the information are the only identifiers, can move to the other page with parameters in the url, but if they are private or heavy data identifiers is best to store them in the session.

regards